# Javascript code not running onbeforeunload

Tags: php, javascript, html, onbeforeunload

I have 3 variables to track timespent in the site

```
 $_SESSION['checkin']; //logged when user first enters the site 
 $_SESSION['loggedAt']; //logged when the user leaves the site
 $_SESSION['timespent']; //time spent in minutes
```

What I'm trying to do is everytime the user leaves the page, these values are pushed into the database. What I've done is use onbeforeunload.

Below is how I'm using it:

On every page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/storeSession.js"></script>
```

storeSession.js:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit();
  function confirmExit()
  {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post','../php/storeSession.php',true);
        xhr.send();
        return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
  }
```

And storeSession.php:

```
$_SESSION['loggedAt'] = time();
$temptime = (double)$_SESSION['timespent']/60;
$_SESSION['timespent'] = $_SESSION['loggedAt'] - $_SESSION['checkin'];

mysql_select_db($db, $conn) or die(mysql_error()); 

$data = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (user_id, timespent) VALUES ($tempuser, $temptime) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE timespent = timespent + $temptime")
        or die(mysql_error()); 

$_SESSION['timespent'] = null;
$_SESSION['loggedAt'] = null;
$_SESSION['checkin'] = null;

mysql_close($con);
```

I can't find the problem and everything seems to be working alright (no errors and such). Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You needed to define the `confirmExit` function before assigning it to the window event. Otherwise you assign `null`.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is this line:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit();
```

You called the function and assigned the return value to `window.onbeforeunload`, instead of assigning the function itself.

Change the line to:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
```

...or use a closure.

Also you are making a POST request without sending any data (you didn't pass anything to the first argument of `send()`) - you probably want to be making a GET request instead.

Comment: Thankyou for the quick reply! I have removed the (), but the database still remains not updated ):

Also switched the request to get.

Comment: @Ohhreeohh You should use something like Chrome developer tools to verify that the request is being sent, and that it is being sent to the correct location. I am also not 100% sure that a relative URL like `'../php/storeSession.php'` will work as expected (it *should* but I've never seen `..` used in an ajax URL before), try using the full URL to your script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the parenthese from your onbefore function

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
```

Also you are ending the session with the XHR call, before the confirm. If the users cancels the unload, he is still logged out.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply! :)
I have removed it, but it doesnt seem to affect anything else.

Also, the alert was for testing purposes in an earlier stage and will be removed before it goes live, so this is fine :)

Comment: You do get the warning message now?

Comment: The warning message runs (even before the edit!) but the database remains unchanged

Comment: My mistake-- The warning message does not run anymore. :s Strange!

Comment: perhaps there is something off with the XHR request. Try to have only the return value and see if it runs the warning message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `onunload` instead of `onbeforeunload`. I remember that the latter one is restricted because it could potentially be used to prevent users from exiting page (or even the browser). I am not completly sure, but i think that (most) browsers only read the returned string and ignore the rest.

Also, i have had some problems with on(before)unload actions myself, and solved them by explicitly using synchronous communication with the server (i used jquery + ajax), otherwise the ajax request wasn't completed (though I have no experience with `XMLHttpRequest`, but i think this option should be comparable)